# Finding a formula for the sums $2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + \cdots + 2^n$

Tags: summation, closed-form, geometric-series

I am told to consider the sum $2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + \cdots + 2^n$ for $n ∈ ℕ ∪ \{0\}$. Next, I am to find the value of the sum for $n= 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$. After I find those values, I am supposed to come up with a conjecture that gives a simple closed formula. When I did the sums, I realize that the difference between sums doubles every time. So,

$n=0$ is $1$,

$n=1$ is $3$,

$n=2$ is $7$,

$n=3$ is $15$,

$n=4$ is $31$.

My problem is that I am having a hard time trying to come up with a conjecture. How would I be able to come up with one? Is it just Guess and Check?

Comment: Hint: Compare the values for each $n$ with $2^{n+1}$

Comment: I see it now. Thank you!

Comment: With $2^{n+1}-1$.

Comment: @Hamou Hint $\neq$ Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the difference doubles every (they are 2, 4, 8, 16) we have $x_{n+1}=x_n+2^{n+1}$. So using this we can see
$$x_n=\sum_{n=0}^n2^{n}$$

This is a finite [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Generalized_formula), so it is given by
\begin{align*}x_n=\sum_{n=0}^n2^{n}&=\frac{1-2^{n+1}}{1-2} \\&=2^{n+1}-1\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

**Without words**:

$$2S=2(2^0+2^1+\cdots 2^n)=2^1+2^2+\cdots 2^{n+1}=-2^0+S+2^{n+1}.$$

---

**Graphically**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

In a more general manner, if $$x_n=\sum_{n=0}^n k^{n}$$ you face a geometric progression and whatever $k$ could be (except $k=1$) you should end with $$x_n=\sum_{n=0}^n k^{n}=\frac{k^{n+1}-1}{k-1}$$

Still more general, if $$x_n=\sum_{m}^n k^{n}=\frac{k^{n+1}-k^m}{k-1}$$